# How to avoid changing background color of a chart with TeeChart Pro 2017 in Delphi10?

Tags: delphi, teechart

I'm using this code to draw a cross on my chart based on my mouse position

```
//Setup color 
Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
Canvas.Pen.Width := 1;
CrossSize := 30;
Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmNotXor;
Canvas.Pen.Color := clGray;
//Draw the cross
Canvas.MoveTo(X - CrossSize, Y);
Canvas.LineTo(X + CrossSize, Y);
Canvas.MoveTo(X, Y - CrossSize);
Canvas.LineTo(X, Y + CrossSize);
```

If the Pen.Mode is pmNotXor, my chart background color is changed to light gray when my mouse moved out of the chart.
If the Pen.Mode is pmXor, the background color turns black.

This code works perfectly with an older version of TChart and Delphi XE4. I only have this issue when upgrading our software to Delphi10 and TeeChart Pro 2017.

Following is a screen shoot of this issue.
[White background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiQwH.jpg) vs after moving the cursor (which trigger the draw a cross function) [Gray background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ5vM.jpg).

Does anyone has any idea what am I using wrong here or is it a bug related to Delphi 10?

Regards,
Vu

Comment: Could you please arrange a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Victoria's answer, but is the way I do it.

```
var
  SavePen: TPen;
begin
  SavePen := TPen.Create;
  try
    SavePen.Assign( Canvas.Pen );
      // modify the pen
    Canvas.Pen.Assign( SavePen );      
  finally
    SavePen.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It is arguable whether the assignment back to the canvas Pen should be inside the finally clause. Your choice, really.

Comment: Dsm, thanks for your answer. I've tried your suggestion but it didn't help me. It seems that the Pen.Mode pmNotXor is not working with my version of TChart pro and Delphi 10. What version of Delphi that you are using?

Comment: Hello Dusty, Could you please as tell Yeray, a simple example where we can reproduce the problem here and try to find a solution for you? 
Thanks in advance